# How to get a simple phpunit codecoverage summary in text output?

Tags: phpunit, php-code-coverage

I use PHPUnit 9.5.7 on php 8.0.3
I would like to have a checker for minimum code coverage of lines as a git hook.

I have seen in online examples a simple 3 line output as a summary after running the tests. How do I get this output? I searched several articles and the config documentation but didn't find anything.

My aim is to deny the commit if a minimal coverage of lines isn't achieved. So if you have other ideas to get this done I am open.

Here is my current configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd"
    backupGlobals="false"
    colors="true"
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    cacheResult="false"
    printerClass="Codedungeon\PHPUnitPrettyResultPrinter\Printer"
>
  <coverage>
    <include>
      <directory>src</directory>
    </include>
  </coverage>
  <php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
    <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="\App\Kernel" />
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
    <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1"/>
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value=""/>
    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak"/>
    <env name="CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN" value="^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$"/>
  </php>
  <extensions>
    <extension class="DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitExtension"/>
  </extensions>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you refer to is the [phpunit text-output for coverage](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/textui.html#command-line-options):

```
  --coverage-text=<file>      Generate code coverage report in text format [default: standard output]
```

---

An alternative to it is a small script that you can run after running the tests with coverage to check on the gathered data.

Here an excerpt from a `composer.json`  `{"script": {}}` section:

```json
    "unit-test": [
      "@phpunit --log-junit build/log/junit.xml --coverage-clover build/log/clover.xml test/unit",
      "@php -f lib/build/coverage-checker.php -- build/log/clover.xml"
    ],
```

Taken from an existing project which has the script:

- https://github.com/ktomk/pipelines/blob/master/lib/build/coverage-checker.php

It is a maintained version that originated in this blog-post:

- http://ocramius.github.io/blog/automated-code-coverage-check-for-github-pull-requests-with-travis/

The percentage to check for by default is 100%. You can pass it as the second positional argument if you would like to lower it.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent formulated answer, I will give feedback as soon as I can test it. That looks very promising!

Comment: I had to change one line to make it run in my environment: line 95 ```printf('  %6.2f: %s%s', $coverage, $file->attributes()['name'], PHP_EOL);```

Comment: What's the purpose of the "@" (@phpunit / @php) ?   My guess is to prevent echoing the command...   but doesn't seem to do anything on OSX

Comment: @BradKent: No, this is specific to composer scripts and it a) can reference another script or b) specify the (php) executable. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#referencing-scripts - https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#executing-php-scripts